# Как добавить разницу в цикл?

Tags: unrealscript

Имеется метод:

```
function proceed()
{
  for(int i=0; i<3;i++)
  {
    Use(MyArray[i].object)
  }
}
```

Он перебирает объекты из массива через цикл(и использует попавшийся объект), проблема в том что сам метод вызывается по таймеру, и от таймера зависит какой из объектов должен будет использоваться.

```
function OnTimer(int TimerID)
{
    int i;
    switch (TimerID)
    {
        case TIMER_init://если прошло достаточно времени таймер сработает
        proceed();
        break;
    }
}
```

И когда таймер срабатывает нужным образом(к примеру:вызывает сам метод третий раз), цикл итрирует первый объект - вместо третьего, каким образом можно добавить или представить этот цикл так чтобы в него добавлялась эта разница.
То есть при последующих срабатываниях после первого, вызывался второй объект, и после второго вызывался третий объект !
Как можно представить [i] итиратор для объекта, зависящий от того - какой раз сработал таймер, может и не нужно использовать For loop, Но как тогда это все представить ?
К примеру добавить counter в OnTimer Switch{}, нечего не даст, то есть counter++ - всегда будет равен 1, даже если сам метод сработал не первый раз(Специфика языка Uscript);
Что можете посоветовать в таком случае - не трудоемкого ?

Comment: так с++ или Uscript? Судя по синтаксису - не C++, стоит поправить метку, чтобы не сбивала с толку других. В любом случае, как написано сейчас, должен срабатывать вызов всех объектов массива, при любом сработавшем таймере. А как должно быть в результате? Каждый объект срабатывает по своему таймеру, или по одному и тому же, но в зависимости от числа срабатываний?

Comment: @rdorn Unrealscript Это и есть C++, в более упрошенном виде. Проблема тут в том чтобы итиратор объектов массива был динамическим и зависил от числа срабатываний метода(который срабатывает по таймеру, т с задержкой в N секунд) P.S. Тега Unrealscript почему то нету

Comment: т.е. я правильно понял, что по срабатыванию таймера, должен обрабатываться следующий объект из массива и так по кругу?

Comment: Тег можно указать даже если его еще нет, главное чтобы он соответствовал содержимому

Comment: @rdorn Да правильно, на счет тега - рейтинга не хватает

Comment: метку поправил, ждем принятия правки. А по вопросу - вам просто нужна самая обычная очередь. Метод вызываемый по таймеру берет элемент из начала очереди, обрабатывает и кладет в конец. К сожалению я не силен в библиотеках UScript, но наверняка там есть что-то типа Queue, для организации очереди без вело-строительства.

Comment: @rdorn я бы мог вообще ограничеться просто использования счетчика counter++; но после каждого срабатывания таймера(метода) счетчик обнуляеться и снова показывает 1, может можно придумать какой то Saver ? ибо queue такого чтобы работал с эллементами массива, там вроде нету,

Comment: ок, вызов принят =) даже если нет (документацию по языку нашел, но не еще не докопался) реализуйте очередь "в лоб", через сдвиг элементов в массиве. Или подсмотрите реализацию тут http://ericdives.com/UT2004-UnCodex/Source_engine/announcerqueuemanager.html

Comment: @rdorn Я в принципе так и хотел, но это капец костыль =D , я частично реализовал, но есть 1 проблема , за переключение/сдвиг элементов у меня отвечает 1 переменная, если объект[0] прошел(т.е таймер сработал) переменная принимает значение 1, и в последующем итрировании Объект[0] не участвует, но когда все объекты прошли как надо, как заставить объект[0] снова быть задействованым в цикле т.е вернуть значение переменной на 0. ведь если делать проверку на if([i]==Array.length) в ней будет участвовать объект не под индексом [0], и просто -1 либо +1, Тут не помогут, ибо я включу только объект 0

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36979/discussion-between-rdorn-and-lighfusion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Организуем циклический сдвиг массива:

```
function proceed()
{
    if (MyArray.Length > 0)
    {
        Use(MyArray[0].object);
        var TypeOfArrayElement temp = MyArray[0];
        MyArray.Remove(0, 1);
        if (temp.object.isDone != 1)
        {
            MyArray[MyArray.Length] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Если я правильно понял что требуется, то это должно дать нужный результат.

Как оказалось в версии UE ниже 3.0 много "особенностей" =( так что если вы работаете сто старой версией, код может оказаться не рабочим